# Limit of sum function for infinite series $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^6+x^4}$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

As the title states I would like to determine the limit of $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^6+x^4}$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. My gut instinct here tells me that the limit should be 0 as each of the terms would go to 0, however I am having difficulty finding any formal reason as to why:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)$

If it were a finite sum then this would be easy enough, however the fact that I'm working with an infinite sum is causing me some trouble, I'd deeply appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result follows directly by Dominated Convergence. But here's an elementary argument. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $m$ such that $\sum_{n>m}\frac1{n^6}<\frac\varepsilon2$. If $x>(2m/\varepsilon)^{1/4}$, then
$$
\sum_n\frac1{n^6+x^4}\leq\frac\varepsilon2+\sum_{n=1}^m\frac1{n^6+x^4}
\leq\frac\varepsilon2+\sum_{n=1}^m\frac1{x^4}
=\frac\varepsilon2+\frac m{x^4}<\varepsilon.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{n^6+x^4} \leqslant \frac{1}{n^6}$$
So you can get any property you would like from uniformly convergence:

General theorem about interchange limit and summation for uniformly convergence series holds also for any point $x_0$, finite or not("ε/3 trick"), which is density point for $f$ domain, so you can use $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)$$

Comment: That's where I'm having trouble, I'm not sure as to how I find the desired property from uniform convergence.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question

Comment: @Elliot G. Added to answer. I thought it's well known, but if you would like have exact citation, then theorem is in Fichtenholz, G. M. Differential and integral calculus, II volume. I couldn't find link in internet in English. For in Russian variant (472p., 2003) there are a lot of links.

Comment: @Emil Lenler. Added to answer. Citation in answer to Elliot G.'s comment above - it did not allow me to answer both simultaneously. So, you can use interchange limit and summation outgoing from uniformly convergence, also, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is $0$ because, for any large $N\in\Bbb N$,$$f(N)=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n^6+N^4}+\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^6+N^4}\le\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{N^4}}_{N^{-3}}+\underbrace{\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^6}}_{\sim\tfrac15N^{-5}}\in N^{-3}+O(N^{-5}).$$Since $f$ decreases with increasing $N$, $f(x)\le f(\lfloor x\rfloor)$ for all $x\ge0$.